# Absolute value in solution of differential equation and singular solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question 1:** In differential equation $x +xy +y' (y+xy)=0$, when we are separating variables we have to divide by $1+x$ and $1+y$ and we get following: $ \frac{xdx}{x+1} = -\frac{ydy}{1+y}$.  Do we have to check if $y=-1$ and $x = -1$ are singular solutions?

**Question 2:** The solution of this equation is: $ x +y= ln|1+x|+ln|1+y|+c$. When I simplify this, I get: $x+y =  ln|1+x|+ln|1+y|+ln|c_{1}|= ln(|c_{1}||1+x||1+y|)$.

Can this be written as:  $x+y= ln|1+x||1+y|c_{2}$ (so without absolute value, if I assume that
$c_{2}= |c_{1}| \cdot sgn(1+x) \cdot sgn(1+y) $ ? In general, can constant contain the sign of some variables?

Comment: Concerning question 1: Depends on what you have to do. $y = -1$should be treated separately in order to check whether this is a singular solution. Note that there could even be more singular solutions of the equation.

Comment: If we insert  y = 1 in the equation, we get 0=0, which is true. Does it mean that the line y = 1 is singular solution? Is that the only singular solution in this case?